# How to mathematically convert an array of bytes to a decimal value

Tags: logic

With C# I can convert an array of bytes to a decimal value:

```
//F4 6C 56 7D AE C6 4B 40

var bytes = new byte[] { 244, 108, 86, 125, 174, 198, 75, 64 };
var value = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, 0); //=55.5522
```

I would like to know how this works and be able to express it by hand on paper.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Base_conversion

Comment: [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format: binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64)

Comment: https://github.com/stdlib-js/number-float64-base-from-binary-string and https://github.com/stdlib-js/number-float32-base-from-binary-string